# Convergence of series (Need suggestion)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I recently went through the concept of summation of series. I was studying about the convergence and divergence of series. I went through the Wikipedia page about convergence tests. I found that there are many of them. I wanted to know which ones are important and are mostly applied in solving problems.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful will be the ratio test and the comparison test. These two will provide answer most of the times. If they fail to answer, the integral test can be very usfeul (though it may be hard to compute integrals of series for which the previous tests failed).